# Why $push is not adding newCategory

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to push the new category to existing category but it's not doing so and returning an empty array.

I also tried it with `.save()` but it didn't help much.

//post route

```
router.post('/category', middleware.isAdmin, upload.single('category[image]'), async  function(req,res, next){
try {
    let result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path,{  // upload image to cloudinary
     folder: 'category_images',
     use_filename: true
    }); 
    let categories = await Category.find({});
    let i = await categories.findIndex((e) => e.name === req.body.category.name); // find if category name already exits
    if(i === -1){
        let newCategory = {   //create new category name
            name : req.body.category.name,
            image : result.secure_url,
            imageId : result.public_id
        };
        // categories.push(newCategory);
        // categories.save();
        // // Category.save();

        await Category.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user.cart.id}, {$push: {categories: newCategory}}); // push the newCategory to existing category array
        let categories = await Category.find({});

        console.log(categories);
        req.flash('success','category added to db');
        console.log(categories);
    }
    else {
        req.flash('error', 'categorory already exits');
    }
    res.redirect('back');
}
catch(err){
    req.flash('error', err.message, err.name);
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect('back');
}
});
```

// mongoose schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    categories : [
       {
        name: String,
        image : String,
        ImageId : String
      }
     ] 
  }
 );
module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

it's returning `[]` when I do `Category.find({})`.

Comment: Instead of pushing just try to directly assigning the value to categories key. This is because while you are creating a document $push doesn't make sense. At this time directly assigning should work.

Comment: but, I also want to save the upcoming categories in the same category array. when I'll assign it, it will lose previous categories.

Comment: While creating it you can you can assign and when you are updating use $push to insert the value into an array. Look the concept behind this is when you are creating a document you don't have any array where you can push the data this is the reason $push doesn't works in create where as when you are updating the document with findOneAndUpdate or update you might have an array so you can push your values into it.